# How to get aws cli to accept a yaml file for --target-tracking-configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cli, aws-auto-scaling

I'm doing something wrong in my command here, and I'm thinking I need a way to tell the cli that the configuration isn't JSON, but YAML.

**Command:**

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --auto-scaling-group-name myasgnamehere --policy-name mypolicynamehere --policy-type TargetTrackingScaling --target-tracking-configuration file://testpolicy.yaml
```

**Error:**

```
Error parsing parameter '--target-tracking-configuration': Expected: '=', received: 'T' for input:
---
TargetValue: 75
^
PredefinedMetricSpecification:
  PredefinedMetricType: ASGAverageCPUUtilization
```

I don't have this issue when I specify the JSON version of the file

Answer (score 0):

I learned I was better off generating a YAML skeleton for put-scaling-policy first:

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy
```

Then building a complete configuration file based on the requirements for my policy, and using less command arguments. Final product looked like this:

```
AutoScalingGroupName: 'MyASGName'
PolicyName: 'MyTargetTrackingScaling'
PolicyType: 'TargetTrackingScaling'
TargetTrackingConfiguration:
    TargetValue: 75
    PredefinedMetricSpecification:
        PredefinedMetricType: ASGAverageCPUUtilization
```

And command:

```
aws autoscaling put-scaling-policy --cli-input-yaml file://testpolicy.yaml
```